# in reactnative using FCM , notification Icon shows default icon and is not displaying icon in payload although icon added in drawable folder

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am working on a react native project , I have a requirement to change the notification icon as specified in the payload. Added the icons in drawable folder, but still the default icon is displayed not the one in payload. I am using onesignal as well in my project.
working in samsung but not in other phones.

Comment: Please add some details. what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.